# JPA repository find by a date field only for a certain month

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have an entity that has a `LocalDateTime` field. I want to query these entities by the month of this date field. I have the following query:

```java
List<MyEntity> findAllByDate_MonthValue(Integer monthValue)
```

This does not work, it produces the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myEntityRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List MyEntityRepository.findAllByDate_MonthValue(Integer)! Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.date] of basic type

I don't get the error, I tried other approaches and none worked. Moreover, I tried to use the `@Query` annotation, but I don't have the `YEAR/MONTH/etc... and neither EXTRACT` functions.

Comment: `but I don't have the YEAR/MONTH/etc... and neither EXTRACT functions.` why?

Comment: Intellij doesn't seem to autocomplete them, and I get compile errors when using them so I don't really know why. I see that they are Hibernate specific, I don't really know myself.

Comment: well you still can use a native query (written in SQL or whatever language your DBMS supports)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Hibernate as the ORM provider, you can use HQL and a query similar to this in order to extract the month value from a given date and compare it to a given integer value. Consider the following example:

1. Entity class

```java
@Table(name = "SomeEntity")
@Entity(name = "SomeEntity")
@Data
public class SomeEntityClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String someColumn;

    @Basic
    private ZonedDateTime someDate;

}
```

And the following repository interface:

2. Repository

```java
public interface SomeEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntityClass, Long> {

    @Query(
        name = "SomeEntityClass.findAllByMonth",
        value = "SELECT E FROM SomeEntity E WHERE MONTH(E.someDate) = :monthValue"
    )
    List<SomeEntityClass> findAllByMonth(@Param("monthValue") Integer monthValue);

}
```

I hope this is something that is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a reference to a month.

You need to convert your query in something like:

```
findAllByDateBetween
```

this method will take two dates that are used as minor and major limit of the query. So you need to create a method to get the first day of month and first day of next month to correctly call this method.

A complete list of all keywords accepted in the JPA methods is available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) and the reference to the Between keyword is the following:

```
Keyword    Example                  JPQL Snippet
---------------------------------------------------
Between    findByStartDateBetween   ... where x.startDate between ?1 and ?2
```